# Select Kendo ComboBox in Cypress

Tags: testing, kendo-ui, automation, cypress

I have problem with selecting value from combobox in Cypress.
It allways writes me that:

```
CypressError: cy.select() can only be called on a <select>. Your subject is a: <span unselectable="on" class="k-select" aria-label="select" role="button" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="fabric_listbox">...</span>
Types text into numeric inputs
```

My code looks like this:

```
describe('KendoUI', () => {

  it('types text into numeric inputs', () => {

    cy.visit('https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/combobox/index');

    cy.get(':nth-child(4) > .k-dropdown-wrap > .k-select').select('Polyester')
  })
})
```

Can you please give me some help?
You could try it on this page: https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/combobox/index

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I resolved it.

1. Make `cy.click()` on the element
2. Found with `cy.contains()` text what is in the box and then click on it (`cy.contains('text').click`)

Answer (score 3):

`cy.get('kendo-popup').contains('Foobar').click({force:true})`

You might need to force click as the element might not be visible

Answer (score 2):

`cy.select()` will only work for native HTML `<select>` elements. In your case you should simply `cy.click()` on the element you want to select. This is the way for all custom plugins which mimic select behaviour.

Comment: Ok, but how can I find in playground which value I want to select? After I will click on that it only shows get function.

Answer (score 0):

```
cy.get('combobox').contains('value').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that Cypress scrolling the viewport to the chosen option caused the dropdown to close. This command tells Cypress to wait for the dropdown to become non-disabled, scroll to the dropdown, click on the dropdown, wait for the dropdown to finish animating, then click on the item without further scrolling.

Tested with Kendo UI v2016.1.226

Declaration in `commands.js`:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('selectKendoDropdownItem', (dropdownName, item) => {
    cy.get(`span[aria-disabled="false"][aria-owns="${dropdownName}_listbox"]`)
        .click()
        .get(`div#${dropdownName}-list li.k-item`)
        .contains(item)
        .click({ waitForAnimations: true, scrollBehavior: false, force: true });
});
```

Use in a spec:
`cy.selectKendoDropdownItem('dropdownElementId', 'Text of option to select');`